# UWP drag and drop custom type/class

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, win-universal-app

Hy there,
I'm trying to enable drag & drop between 2 GridViews, I managed to do it with the custom types of the "DataPackage" class (SetText, SetBitmap, etc..) but I can't figure out how to do this with a custom class/type.
Both GridViews are data-bound to the same custom class (only a couple of properties, int, string, bitmapimage), I simply would like to drag directly this data items from one GridView to the other.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue please check this example I used Behaviors because I used MVVM pattern but I did this for ListView but is the same for GridView with small changes.

Change the Behaviors `<ListView>` to `<GridView>`

This behavior is attached in the ListView where you want drag the item

```
public class StartingDragBehavior:Behavior<ListView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.CanDragItems = true;
        this.AssociatedObject.DragItemsStarting += AssociatedObject_DragItemsStarting;
    }


    private void AssociatedObject_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Data.RequestedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        if(e.Items!=null && e.Items.Any())
        {
            e.Data.Properties.Add("item", e.Items.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.DragItemsStarting -= AssociatedObject_DragItemsStarting;

    }
}
```

This behavior is attached in the ListView where you want to drop the item
Here another Behavior to catch the drop event.

```
public class EndDropBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.AllowDrop = true;
        this.AssociatedObject.Drop += AssociatedObject_Drop;
        this.AssociatedObject.DragOver += AssociatedObject_DragOver;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Drop(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView != null &&
            e.DataView.Properties != null &&
            e.DataView.Properties.Any(x => x.Key == "item" && x.Value.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)))
        {
            try
            {
                var def = e.GetDeferral();

                var item = e.Data.Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "item");
                var card = item.Value as MyObject;


                    var list = sender as ListView;
                    var vm = list.DataContext as Infrastructure.ViewModels.CreditCardsViewModel;


                        vm.MyCollection.Add(card);

                def.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

            }

        }
        else
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.None;
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_DragOver(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView != null &&
            e.DataView.Properties != null &&
            e.DataView.Properties.Any(x => x.Key == "item" && x.Value.GetType() == typeof(MyObject)))
        {

            e.AcceptedOperation = e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Copy;

        }
        else
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.None;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.Drop -= AssociatedObject_Drop;

        this.AssociatedObject.DragOver -= AssociatedObject_DragOver;
    }
}
```

If you are not using MVVM pattern just check the events of the to Behaviors.

Comment: Thank you Riccardo, your answer pointed me in the right direction:
"e.Data.Properties.Add" allowed me to add my custom type as a property and with "e.Data.Properties.TryGetValue()" you get an object you can then cast to your custom type.
Worked pretty well!

Comment: And that helped me, thanks! Only difference is that I needed to use e.DataView.Properties.TryGetValue() ...

Answer (score 5):

So to summarize for the benefit of others, I added these to event handlers to DataTemplate content, as I only wanted items of a certain (ViewModel) type to be draggable.

```
    private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            var targetIvm = fe.DataContext as ItemViewModel;
            object obj = null;
            if(e.DataView.Properties.TryGetValue("ItemViewModel", out obj))
            {
                var sourceIvm = obj as ItemViewModel;
                vm.MoveItem(sourceIvm, targetIvm);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Grid_DragStarting(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            var item = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ItemViewModel", fe.DataContext);
            args.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
            args.Data.Properties.Add("ItemViewModel", fe.DataContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's helpful, do you know how to figure out the insert point? My GridView is CanReorderItems so it makes a space to drop, but during Drop() I have only managed to Remove from one ObservableCollection and Add to another. (I have three separate GridViews, but I could maybe try one with groups....)